# On fit_generator() / fit() and thread-safety

Tags: python, multithreading, keras, multiprocessing, thread-safety

***Context***

In order to use `fit_generator()` in Keras I use a generator-function like this *pseudocode*-one:

```py
def generator(data: np.array) -> (np.array, np.array):
    """Simple generator yielding some samples and targets"""

    while True:
        for batch in range(number_of_batches):
            yield data[batch * length_sequence], data[(batch + 1) * length_sequence]
```

In Keras' `fit_generator()` function I want to use `workers=4` and `use_multiprocessing=True` - Hence, I need a threadsafe generator.

In answers on stackoverflow like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54524124/dimension-mismatch-in-keras-during-model-fit/54626839#54626839) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50600624/how-to-use-fit-generator-with-sequential-data-that-is-split-into-batches?rq=1) or in the Keras [docs](https://keras.io/utils/#sequence), I read about creating a class inheriting from `Keras.utils.Sequence()` like this:

```py
class generatorClass(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size):
        self.x, self.y = x_set, y_set
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.ceil(len(self.x) / float(self.batch_size)))

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.x[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
        batch_y = self.y[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]

        return ...
```

By using `Sequences` Keras does not throw any warning using multiple workes and multiprocessing; the generator is supposed to be threadsafe.

Anyhow, since I am using my custom function I stumbled upon Omer Zohars code provided on [github](https://gist.github.com/platdrag/e755f3947552804c42633a99ffd325d4) which allows to make my `generator()` threadsafe by adding a decorator.
The code looks like:

```py
import threading

class threadsafe_iter:
    """
    Takes an iterator/generator and makes it thread-safe by
    serializing call to the `next` method of given iterator/generator.
    """
    def __init__(self, it):
        self.it = it
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        with self.lock:
            return self.it.__next__()


def threadsafe_generator(f):
    """A decorator that takes a generator function and makes it thread-safe."""
    def g(*a, **kw):
        return threadsafe_iter(f(*a, **kw))

    return g
```

Now I can do:

```py
@threadsafe_generator
def generator(data):
    ...
```

The thing is: Using this version of a threadsafe generator Keras still emits a warning that the generator has to be threadsafe when using `workers > 1` and `use_multiprocessing=True` and that this can be avoided by using `Sequences`.

***My questions now are:***

1. Does Keras emit this warning only because the generator is not inheriting `Sequences`, or does Keras also check if a generator is threadsafe in general?
2. Is using the approach I choosed as threadsafe as using the `generatorClass(Sequence)`-version from the [Keras-docs](https://keras.io/utils/#sequence)?
3. Are there any other approaches leading to a thread-safe-generator Keras can deal with which are different from these two examples?

---

**Edit:**
In newer `tensorflow`/`keras`-versions (`tf` > 2) `fit_generator()` is deprecated. Instead, it is recommended to use `fit()` with the generator. However, the question still applies to `fit()` using a generator as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

During my research on this I came across some information answering my questions.

**Note**: As updated in the question in newer `tensorflow`/`keras`-versions (`tf` > 2) `fit_generator()` is deprecated. Instead, it is recommended to use `fit()` with the generator. However, the answer still applies to `fit()` using a generator as well.

---

> **1.** Does Keras emit this warning only because the generator is not inheriting Sequences, or does Keras also check if a generator is threadsafe in general?

Taken from Keras' gitRepo ([training_generators.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training_generator.py)) I found in lines `46-52` the following:

```py
use_sequence_api = is_sequence(generator)
if not use_sequence_api and use_multiprocessing and workers > 1:
    warnings.warn(
        UserWarning('Using a generator with `use_multiprocessing=True`'
                    ' and multiple workers may duplicate your data.'
                    ' Please consider using the `keras.utils.Sequence'
                    ' class.'))
```

The definition of `is_sequence()` taken from [training_utils.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training_utils.py) in lines `624-635` is:

```py
def is_sequence(seq):
    """Determine if an object follows the Sequence API.
    # Arguments
        seq: a possible Sequence object
    # Returns
        boolean, whether the object follows the Sequence API.
    """
    # TODO Dref360: Decide which pattern to follow. First needs a new TF Version.
    return (getattr(seq, 'use_sequence_api', False)
            or set(dir(Sequence())).issubset(set(dir(seq) + ['use_sequence_api'])))
```

Regarding this piece of code Keras only checks if a passed generator is a Keras-sequence (or rather uses Keras' sequence API) and does not check if a generator is threadsafe in general.

---

> **2.** Is using the approach I choosed as threadsafe as using the generatorClass(Sequence)-version from the [Keras-docs](https://keras.io/utils/#sequence)?

As Omer Zohar has shown on [gitHub](https://gist.github.com/platdrag/e755f3947552804c42633a99ffd325d4) his decorator is threadsafe - I don't see any reason why it shouldn't be as threadsafe for Keras (even though Keras will warn as shown in 1.).
The implementation of `thread.Lock()` can be concidered as threadsafe according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Lock):

> A factory function that returns a new primitive lock object. *Once a thread has acquired it, subsequent attempts to acquire it block, until it is released*; any thread may release it.

The generator is also picklable, which can be tested like (see this SO-Q&A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43730275/keras-pickle-safe-what-does-it-mean-to-be-pickle-safe-or-alternatively-n) for further information):

```py
#Dump yielded data in order to check if picklable
with open("test.pickle", "wb") as outfile:
    for yielded_data in generator(data):
        pickle.dump(yielded_data, outfile, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Resuming this, I would even suggest to implement `thread.Lock()` when you extend Keras' `Sequence()` like:

```py
import threading

class generatorClass(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size):
        self.x, self.y = x_set, y_set
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.lock = threading.Lock()   #Set self.lock

    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.ceil(len(self.x) / float(self.batch_size)))

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        with self.lock:                #Use self.lock
            batch_x = self.x[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
            batch_y = self.y[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]

            return ...
```

**Edit 24/04/2020:**

By using `self.lock = threading.Lock()` you might run into the following error:

> TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects

In case this happens try to replace `with self.lock:` inside `__getitem__` with `with threading.Lock():` and comment out / delete the `self.lock = threading.Lock()` inside the `__init__`.

It seems there are some problems when storing the `lock`-object inside a class (see for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44144584/typeerror-cant-pickle-thread-lock-objects) Q&A).

---

> **3.** Are there any other approaches leading to a thread-safe-generator Keras can deal with which are different from these two examples?

During my research I did not encounter any other method.
Of course I cannot say this with 100% certainty.

Comment: Hi. Is it possible to apply your threadsafe inplementation to an imported generator function? If so, how would you do it? I would like to make ImageDataGenerator threadsafe.

Comment: Hi @IsaacNg, as far as I know you can only customize the `generator`-class in this way and not the ImageDataGenerator. Anyhow, I would wonder if Keras' own class (the Image-Gen) would not inherit from the generator-class itself, which is threadsafe. To be sure just check out the underlying code of the ImageDataGenerator-class :)

Comment: Thanks. I found out it inherits from keras sequence so it should be threadsafe.